# I cannot pass variable from activity to fragment using bundle

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am making an app that you can basically post some stuff. What i am trying to do is, i want to insert the things that the user posts to his/her own firebase real time database. So that is why i take the username from register activity and try to pass it with bundle to my fragment for users to post. But i get nullpoint exception as 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()'. Here is my code that passes and recieves bundle:

Register class:

```
    public void sendUserData(){
    String getUserName = username.getText().toString();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("username",getUserName);
    AddFragment addFragment = new AddFragment();
    addFragment.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

AddFragment fragment:

```
try {
        //Get username from register activity
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        uname = bundle.getString("username");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error is:"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Look into using [SharedPreferences](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-on-android-to-store-read-and-edit-values#).

Comment: Which line of code throws a NPE?

Comment: Bundle  bundle = this.getArguments(), when i try to get the bundle in the fragment.